PATH on Mac not working for Python
I am trying to run a Python program from my command line on my Mac. (in this case: python3 Hello.py).
For the life of me, I can’t get it to consider the PATH where the program is located. This is the error message:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/user/Hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. 

I have changed the ~/.zshrc file to add the PATH, but it doesn’t work. Here it is:
PATH="/Users/user/mu_code:${PATH}"
export PATH}. 

Are there any resources for me to check out?
The path to the file contains an underscore, so I have put the path in “”.
Nonetheless it can’t find it. If I type in the full path with the program name, it works fine. Ie.
{python3 /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py}
works fine.
Python is also in the path already automatically after installation. Here is the path (it's in ~/.zprofile):
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Here is the script of the program with shebang.
# This program says hello and asks for my name

#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('Hello world')
print('Whats your name')
myName = input()
print('Its good to meet you,' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('Whats your age?')
myAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge)+1) + ' in a year')



Please [edit] your question and: i) show us the output of echo "$PATH" in the shell that fails to find the command; ii) show us the location of the command,  iii) show us the exact error message you get, iv) tell us which files you have edited (what "all zsh files"?) to add to the PATH and show us the exact lines you added to those files (of course you believe you did it correctly, but maybe you didn't, so we need to see what was done). Also, if you are running python3 Hello.py, then it is python3 that needs to be in your PATH, not Hello.py.

Error message: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/user/Hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
File changed is ~/.zshrc: content is: ATH="/Users/user/mu_code:${PATH}"
export PATH. Python is also in the path already automatically after installation. Here is the path (its in /.zprofile): PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH.

Please EDIT your question and add the answer to all four things I asked for. Don't answer in the comments, as you can see, they are hard to read and format well. Instead, add the details to the question and use the {} button to format the commands and their output as code.

Also show us the output of ls -l /Users/user/Hello.py'. Your error suggests that is simply not the name of the file.

the file is in /Users/user/mu_code. This returns after ls -1 /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py. -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  staff  325 Dec 31 09:00 /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py

I fixed the formatting. I assume that you meant ~/.zshrc and not /.zshrc and that the extra { } were because I mentioned the {} button (I meant the actual button on the editor here on this website).

To check where env is, you can run which env but it will almost certainly be where I suggested.

The command you are running is python3 and you are giving that command the string Hello.py as an argument. The python3 executable will therefore try to find a file named Hello.py in the current directory. The PATH variable is completely irrelevant here, that is only useful to find commands (executables), not files you give as arguments to commands.
If you want to be able to run the script directly, then you need to make sure it has a shebang line. Open Hello.py and make sure the first line is (assuming your env is in /usr/bin, let me know if not):
#!/usr/bin/env python3

Then, make the file executable:
chmod a+x /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py

Now, since you have /Users/user/mu_code in your PATH variable, you can run the script by simply executing
Hello.py

If you want to run it as an argument to python3, then you will always need to run either python3 /full/path/to/Hello.py or first cd /full/path/to/ and then python3 Hello.py.

Unfortunately it's not working (yet). It does find the file now after typing 'Hello.py'. I did add Shebang. However it doesnt run the program. It gives the following error. /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token 'Hello world'' /Users/user/mu_code/Hello.py: line 4: print('Hello world')'

@user61392 that's a whole different issue. The script is running, but the script has a syntax error. That's a pure python issue, you could try posting a new question on [so] showing your code. But it is running.

Hang on, is there a windows machine involved here? Could you have windows line endings in the file? Or is there actually an extra ' after the closing parenthesis of the print statement?

There is nothing wrong with the program. I ran it many times. I am on a MAC. If i run the Hello.py with the correct file routing, it works correct.
